# What is my ip when visiting localhost

Tags: php, ip

I made a page which is only accessible for specific ip addresses.

Code:

```
// IP's that are allowed.
$allow = array("123.456.7.89", "987.654.3.21"); //allowed IPs

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow)) {

header("Location: http://www.google.com"); //redirect

exit();

}
```

But if I visit my localhost, I can't visit it because it says my ip is 0.0.0.0

What to fill in as allowed ip?

Comment: Both your allowed ip's cannot exist.

Comment: @jmattheis this is just an example of 2 ip's.

Comment: Still each block can only can take 8 bits (0-255) as you have 456 and 987 in there it isn't a valid ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try visiting your localhost on another device, and use that ip.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're getting a valid IP Address.

Try this:

```
$ip = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

var_dump($ip); // Check if IP is valid

$allow = array("123.456.7.89", "987.654.3.21"); //allowed IPs

if (!in_array($ip, $allow)) {
    header("Location: http://www.google.com"); //redirect
    exit();
}
```

Reference: [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: What do I need to enter than as allowed ip, if I visit on localhost? Because if I visit it on my mobile phone I am getting a valid ip, and it works if I put that in the allowed ip's. But I am getting 0.0.0.0 for my pc, which doesn't works.